# Can we define Urysohn function here?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space such that any two distinct points $x,y$ in $X$ can be separated by open subsets $U,V$ of $X$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $cl(U), cl(V)$ are disjoint. For any distinct $x,y$, is it possible to define a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ on $X$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=0$?

I think this is related to the Urysohn function, but from what I understand, for Urysohn function to exist, it is required that $X$ to be normal first and I can't prove that $X$ is normal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for helping (again) and for pointing that out. I have made a big mistake in the condition of $X$ and have fixed it. I will give it another try then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ satisfying the first condition is is called a [*Uryso(h)n space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn_and_completely_Hausdorff_spaces). A space satisfying the second condition is called a *completely Hausdorff* or *functionally Hausdorff* space. Every completely Hausdorff space is Uryson, but not every Uryson space is completely Hausdorff.

One Uryson space that is not completely Hausdorff is the space called the *Arens square* in Steen & Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology*. It’s defined as follows.

> Let $Q=\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$, and let $S=Q\times Q$. Let $p_0=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $p_1=\langle 1,0\rangle$. For each $r\in\Bbb Q\cap\left(0,\frac12\sqrt2\right)$ let $p_r=\left\langle\frac12,r\sqrt2\right\rangle$, and let $L=\left\{p_r:r\in\Bbb Q\cap\left(0,\frac12\sqrt2\right)\right\}$. Finally, let $X=S\cup L\cup\{p_0,p_1\}$. Points of $S$ have the nbhds that they inherit from the usual topology of $\Bbb R^2$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$\begin{align*}B(0,n)&=\{p_0\}\cup\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in S:x<\frac14\text{ and }y<\frac1n\right\}\text{ and}\\B(1,n)&=\{p_1\}\cup\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in S:x>\frac34\text{ and }y<\frac1n\right\}\;,\end{align*}$$ and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $r\in\Bbb Q\cap\left(0,\frac12\sqrt2\right)$  let $$B(r,n)=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in S\cup L:\frac14<x<\frac34\text{ and }\left|y-r\sqrt2\right|<\frac1n\right\}\;.$$ Then $\{B(0,n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is a local base at $p_0$, $\{B(1,n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is a local base at $p_1$, and $\{B(r,n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is a local base at $p_r$ for each $r\in\Bbb Q\cap\left(0,\frac12\sqrt2\right)$.

It’s not hard to verify that $X$ is Uryson; the key observation is that no point of $X\setminus L$ has the same $y$-coordinate as any point of $L$.

To show that $X$ is not completely Hausdorff, we show that there is no continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(p_0)=0$ and $f(p_1)=1$. Suppose that $f$ is such a function. The sets $\left[0,\frac14\right)$ and $\left(\frac34,1\right]$ are open in $[0,1]$, so their inverse images under $f$ are open in $X$. This means that there are $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $f\big[B(0,m)\big]\subseteq\left[0,\frac14\right)$ and $f\big[B(1,n)\big]\subseteq\left(\frac34,1\right]$. Now choose any $r\in\Bbb Q\cap\left(0,\frac12\sqrt2\right)$ such that $r\sqrt2<\min\left\{\frac1m,\frac1n\right\}$.

Now $f(p_r)$ cannot be in both $\left[0,\frac14\right)$ and $\left(\frac34,1\right]$, so without loss of generality suppose that $f(p_r)\notin\left[0,\frac14\right)$. Then there are $a,b\in(0,1)$ such that $\frac14<a<f(p_r)<b$. Clearly $\left[0,\frac14\right]$ and $[a,b]$ are disjoint closed subsets of $[0,1]$, so their inverse images under $f$ are disjoint closed sets in $X$ that contain open nbhds of $p_0$ and $p_r$, respectively. In fact, $f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac14\right]\right]\supseteq B(0,m)$, and I’ll leave it to you to show that the choice of $r$ ensures that for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$,

$$\big(\operatorname{cl}B(0,m)\big)\cap\operatorname{cl}B(r,k)\ne\varnothing\;,$$

contradicting the disjointness of the inverse images of $\left[0,\frac14\right)$ and $\left(\frac34,1\right]$.